# Should I include control variables in my model even if I am using unit- and time-fixed effects for a panel dataset?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am assessing the relationship between a state law and a health outcome's incidence in a given state and year using multiple years of data. If I use within and between fixed effects (creating a dummy variable for each state and year) should I still adjust for potential confounders at the state level such as demographics and political ideology?